# Is there a way to disable a set of snippets in a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

I'm making an extension for Visual Studio Code and I have a file of optional snippets that I want to have an option to disable.

```
      {
        "language": "xml",
        "path": "./Snippets/Completions.jsonc",
        "enabled": "${config:RwMH.enableCompletions}"
      }
```

I have tried using the if, enabled and when tags with various attempts at the variable naming conventions and nothing has worked.

Comment: make the snippets part of your `CompletionItemProvider`

Comment: Can you add a when clause to each snippet?  It doesn't look like you can batch disable them in the package.json - I don't see support for enabled or enabled there.